# Facebook login button not redirecting

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I can't seem to understand why I'm not being redirected to the appropriate page. It certainly exists. Instead of redirecting me, a screen pops up and just goes away after a second.

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({
        appId: 'ID', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
    {
        window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=ID';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class='fb-login-button' data-show-faces='false' scope='email' data-width='200' data-max-rows='1'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing `FB.Event.subscriber`, try the following:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        if ( typeof response != 'undefined' && typeof response.authResponse != 'undefined' ) {
            window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
        }
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
});
```

The function will return `connected` if the user is logged in, and it will then redirect them to any page your want. You can keep the `FB.Event.subscriber` function in there for users who need to login for the first time, and the above code will work for returning users.

Comment: How can I prompt a first time user to accept the specific scopes that I have defined with my app?

Comment: You can show them the login dialog using `FB.login()`, but it's up to the user to accept the scope and add the application.